# C# WPF change DataGrid row (background) color based on the data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have Datagrid view as you can see below :
[image]
the selected one is "Status" which have 3 kinds of values (Paid, unpaid and other).
I want to make the background of each line based on the status, if it is Unpaid the color be red, if its Paid the color is green, and in other options its white or no color.
I recive data from mysql database.
my datagrid XML code:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="178" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,193,63,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1087"  x:Name="FactorGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadDataBinding}" CanUserResizeRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ContextMenuOpening="FactorGrid_ContextMenuOpening">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="شماره صورتحساب" Width="110" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding factorgroup}" Header="گروه" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding factortype}" Header="نوع" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding amount}" Header="مبلغ" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding discount}" Header="تخفیف" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding extra}" Header="جریمه" Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding created_at, ConverterCulture=fa-IR, StringFormat=yyyy/MM/dd}" Header="تاریخ ایجاد" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding parent_id}" Header="شماره صورتحساب اصلی" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding status}"  Header="وضعیت" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="پرداخت شده" Click="BtnSetPaid">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="img/yes.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="پرداخت صورتحساب" Click="BtnAddNewpay_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="img/9999.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="حذف" Click="BtnFactorDell">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="img/delete.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="قسط بندی" Click="BtnFactorSplit">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="img/ab-report.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="ویرایش" Click="BtnFactorEdit">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="img/Edit.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

and my cs codes:

```
MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT query ", conn);
                        MySqlDataAdapter adp2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
                        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                        adp2.Fill(ds2, "LoadDataBinding");
                        FactorGrid.DataContext = ds2;
```

is there any way to do what I wanted to do? sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to DataTriggers.  They can help you bind to a value and do  different things based on the different values. You would typically add this between the </DataGrid.Columns> and <DataGrid.ContextMenu>.  Change the colour RGB to suit.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Paid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#447cff8b"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Unpaid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444eafff"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: one question, is there anyway to chose a color for other values? i mean paid = green unpaid = yellow and if the text was something else red

Comment: Yes, change the Value="#447cff8b" to what ever colour you want for EACH ONE.  

These are ARGB values, so the first 2 digits are the alpha (colour transparency), the next 2 are the red value, the next get green and the final two are blue.  like this AA RR GG BB.

If you want red then set the RR to FF and the  GG BB to 00000, then change the first 2 (AA) to suit how transparent you want them, e.g. Red = 80FF0000.    For green use 8000FF00, blue 800000FF.   Change the 80 for the transparency.  Lower numbers are more transparent, higher numbers less transparent.

Comment: If you want more variations, add more data triggers based on the variation you want.  On the first line of each datatrigger there is a Value field (e.g. Value="Paid" or Value="Unpaid").  If you wanted another one for a different value, add another data trigger for that value and specify the background value as needed.

Comment: i understand the way it works but i want to make something like Value = "paid" green , value = "unpaid" red , and other values yellow no matter what is it, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Following your further question (in the comments) about a **default** value if no other conditions are met, you need to add just one more line:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#4400ffff"></Setter>
```

This goes outside of the style triggers like this (3rd line):

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4400ffff"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Paid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#447cff8b"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Unpaid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444eafff"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This way, if one of the triggers is hit it will take the colour from the trigger, otherwise the default value (line 3 above) will be used.

Comment: Did this work for you?